# bootstrap modal trigger event in incorrect order when jquery mobile CSS is included

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, bootstrap-modal

I ran into a case where only backdrop is being display and modal is only displayed after the backdrop is removed. This is the first time I ever ran into this issue after a couple years of using bootstrap and I'm not able to figure out why. When debugging, the callback is never triggered on the first pass. It's only triggered after I click on the backdrop.

Anyone else ran into this issue before? Is it something to do with CSS conflict potentially? Removing jquery-mobile-1.4.2.css seems to help, but I kinda need both of them to work together. The version of bootstrap I'm using is 2.3.2.

```
this.backdrop(function() {
    var transition = $.support.transition && that.$element.hasClass('fade')

    if (!that.$element.parent().length) {
        that.$element.appendTo(document.body) //don't move modals dom position
    }

    that.$element.show()

    if (transition) {
        that.$element[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
    }

    that.$element.addClass('in').attr('aria-hidden', false)

    that.enforceFocus()

    transition ? 
        that.$element.one($.support.transition.end, function() {
            that.$element.focus().trigger('shown')
        }) : 
        that.$element.focus().trigger('shown')
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Mobile and Twitter Bootstrap use the class "fade" and "in" which is causing the conflict.  Here is how I got around it.

1. Create an override style sheet with the following classes (these are copied from the bootstrap.css file and modified so any reference to "fade" or "in" becomes "bootstrap-fade" and "bootstrap-in" respectively:

   ```
   .modal-backdrop.bootstrap-fade {
     opacity: 0;
   }

   .modal-backdrop,
   .modal-backdrop.bootstrap-fade.bootstrap-in {
     opacity: 0.8;
     filter: alpha(opacity=80);
   }

   .modal.bootstrap-fade {
     -webkit-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
     -o-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
     transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
     top: -25%;
   }

   .modal.bootstrap-fade.bootstrap-in {
     top: 10%;
   }

   .bootstrap-fade {
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
     -o-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
     transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
   }

   .bootstrap-fade.bootstrap-in {
     opacity: 1;
   }

   @media (max-width: 767px) {
       .modal.bootstrap-fade {
           top: -100px;
       }
       .modal.bootstrap-fade.bootstrap-in {
           top: 20px;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Next you need to edit the bootstrap.js file.  You can either copy the entire modal section, (line 61 - 310), or you can edit it directly in the file with find and replace.  Replace all references to "fade" and "in" with your new classes "bootstrap-fade" and "bootstrap-in".  There are 5 instances of "fade" and 4 instances of "in" in the modal section of the js file.
3. Once you have done that, just create your modal normally and use the class "bootstrap-fade" instead of "fade".

   ```
   <div id="myModal" class="modal hide bootstrap-fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby=myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
           <h2 id="assignModalLabel">Modal</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Hope that helps!